# Why swf is always top in HTML component? (Flex,Air)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex-spark

I'm making a game client. The game.swf is on another website. So I'm using HTML component like that:

```
private function htmlLoad(e:Event):void{
        var browser:HTML = new HTML;
        browser.depth = 1;
        browser.location = "http://anotherwebsite.com/game.swf";
        addElement(browser);
}
private function getPanel(e:MouseEvent):void{
        var gamePanel:Panel = new Panel;
        gamePanel.depth = 999;
        addElement(gamePanel)
}
<s:Button click="getPanel(Event)" />
```

I'm clicking the button when swf loaded. But swf is always top. How can I send to back?

Answer (score 0):

Be cause it's a plugin if you  want to  fix it you  need use the z-index from css
eg: 
`#divHtml{
z-index:2;
position:relative
}`

`#divWithFlash{
z-index:-1;
position:relative;
}`

you  may  try position propriets http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: I can't change the css file. I can request the swf only... So I need to change it form Flex.

Comment: you are using a embed file css eg: <href src='css.css' style... > ?

Comment: So i can't see  any exit for it, try to use the rules of http://www.w3.org/ to compatibility for all  browsers